# one category page views only 10 products

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, catalog, layered-navigation

I've one category called `x` it has about 1700 active skus  while it only display 10 on front end

in `public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` :

> $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

has only 10 items.

also there is no observers for this event :

> catalog_product_collection_load_before

any suggestion how to fix ?

**UPDATE** : 
all products are visible and there is no limit on adminhtml , other categories are working as expected

Comment: what's your product per page limit ?

Comment: Check the limits in Config > Catalog > Frontend . Make sure the category's anchor is set to Yes

Comment: there is no limit in adminhtml

Answer (score 0):

Like others have suggested, check product page limit and whether the category has got anchor set to yes if you want to show products in its subcategories.

Also, filters get applied to the product collection in the following method: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection`.

Specifically:

```
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

So that might be where your products are disappearing - they're not allowed to be shown on the page.

Something else you can do is:

```
Zend_Debug::dump((string)$this->_productCollection->getSelect());
```

.. to see what the SQL query looks like if you're suspecting that other event observers are applying filters you don't know about

Also, to be sure, check block cache and full page cache if you've got that turned on/installed.